# Listing indices using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, indexing, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to list all indices in a db using sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[yes](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_indexes).

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection
engine = create_engine('...')
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
for name in insp.get_table_names():
    for index in insp.get_indexes(name):
        print index
```

Comment: Ran into a problem trying to use this:
>>> engine = create_engine('mysql://[my_abs_path]/app.db')
[long dump]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Comment: @SamuelBourque that is a different problem - SQLAlchemy still needs your database python bindings installed before it can connect. Your connect url seems to use mysql but give a path to a sqlite database? To use mysql I suggest installing [oursql](https://pythonhosted.org/oursql/) then using `engine = create_engine('mysql+oursql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')`.

Comment: @SamuelBourque  you need to install a mysql module for communicating with database server.  `pip install mysqlclient` should work out fine.

Answer (score 1):

A little update to [@nosklo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605077/9681081) which is deprecated since SQLAlchemy 1.4.

New code should be:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

engine = create_engine("...")
insp = inspect(engine)
for name in insp.get_table_names():
    for index in insp.get_indexes(name):
        print(index)
```

Note you can also use a `Connection` object as argument to `inspect` - can be more convenient in some cases.