# How do I check which fields have indices in an SQLAlchemy table or class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here's a table definitition using SQLAlchemy declarative_base:

```
t_measures_voyage_crude = Table(
    'measures_voyage_crude', metadata,
    Column('tanker', String(255)),
    Column('load_point', Text),
    Column('load_port', String(255)),
    Column('load_country', NullType),
    Column('load_region', String(255)),
    Column('date_depart', Date),
    Column('offtake_point', Text),
    Column('offtake_port', String(255)),
    Column('offtake_country', NullType),
    Column('offtake_region', String(255)),
    Column('date_arrive', Date),
    Column('grade', Text),
    Column('bbls', BigInteger),
    Column('row_num', Integer, index=True),
    Column('date_num', Integer, index=True),
    Column('stat_num', Integer, index=True),
    schema='numbergo'
)
```

It has three indexed fields, but if I have the table object in a variable, how do I list these columns that have indices?

Similarly for a class, say this one:

```
class MasterBpd(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'master_bpd'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'numbergo'}

    date = Column(Date, primary_key=True)
    bpd_imp_yr = Column(Integer)
    bpd_imp_mo = Column(Integer)
    bpd_imp_wk = Column(Integer)
    bpd_dom_yr = Column(Integer)
    bpd_dom_mo = Column(Integer)
    bpd_dom_wk = Column(Integer)
    row_num = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False, index=True)
    date_num = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False, index=True)
```

How do I check programmatically which fields have indices, and which is the primary key?

Comment: For the ORM side, perhaps you could use `table_name = my_object.__getattribute__("__tablename__")` and then call `indexes = engine.dialect.get_indexes(engine.connect(), table_name)` ?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/inspection.html and https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html should at least point at the right direction, I think.

Comment: These might also help/give ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605019/listing-indices-using-sqlalchemy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878830/sqlalchemy-determine-if-unique-constraint-exists/33898867#33898867

Answer (score 2):

```
for col in MasterBpd.__table__.columns:
   print(col.index) # True if this field has index, None otherwise
   print(col.primary_key) # True if is primary key, False otherwise
```